# Image Slider inside an Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, slider, accordion

I want to put 2 slides inside an accordion, or maybe 2 slides in one page. How can i do this?

[Here's](http://glowinglotus.businesscatalyst.com/programs.html) what i achieved so far.

Here's my code ...

```
 <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Program</h3>
        <div>
        <div id="slides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
 </div>
        </div>


       <h3>Reset</h3>
       <div>
       <div id="slides2">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  </div>
       </div>
       </div>


        <script>
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
</script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
         width: 897,
         height: 750,
         play: {
         active: true,
         auto: true,
         interval: 6000,
         swap: true
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
        <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
          width: 897,
          height: 750,
          play: {
          active: true,
           auto: true,
          interval: 6000,
          swap: true
           }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Is there some conflict with the jQuery effects or something? I'm new to Jquery please help.

Comment: I dont see any element has `id = accordion` in the link provided. Please check again

Comment: weird. it was removed.. just a minute , let me put it back on..

Comment: It's back now, you can check it. thanks!!

Comment: Seems like jquery Ui accordion is conflicting with your slides plugin. try using another accordion.